# htable put and get timeout in java api

Tags: performance, hadoop, nosql, hbase

Is it possible to specify the timeout while doing gets and puts using the java API (the default behavior seems to block forever...especially when our hbase is slow and heavily loaded)

Comment: Try to go through this thread http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/23290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go through this thread comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/23290 – ankitKinra